# JS - Turning a 2d Vector into a curve?

Tags: javascript, vector, curve

I have two Points (x/y) on a canvas an can move an image between them in a straight line using requestanimationframe or setinterval.

However, instead i would like to, somehow ?!, move the object in a curved animation, depending on the vectors combination of velocity x/y and especially s (steps)
I have created this JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/furomu/edit?html,js,console,output - (click init).

Is it possible to somehow turn this "vector" into a curve of some sort to draw smooth movement ?
If not, what other values would i need to turn this into a curved movement ?

```
  //start at 50,50
  //move to 150,125
 // Vector is 100/75 or v +1/+0.75 at 100 steps


function Move(ox, oy, x, y){
  this.ox = ox;
  this.oy = oy;
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.p;
  this.v = {x: x - ox, y: y - oy};

  this.setup = function(){

    var p = {};
    var v = this.v;

    if (this.x > this.y){
      p.s = v.y;
      p.y = 1;
      p.x = v.x/v.y;
    }
    else {
      p.s = v.x;
      p.x = 1;
      p.y = v.y/v.x;
    }

    this.p = p;
  }

  this.setup();
}


function Ship(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.moves = [];

  this.draw = function(){
    this.drawSelf();
    this.drawTarget();
  }

  this.create = function(){
    var move = new Move(this.x, this.y, 150, 125);
    this.moves.push(move);
  }

  this.update = function(){
    var m = this.moves[0];
   var self = this;

   anim = setInterval(function(){          
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, res, res);
      self.x += m.p.x;
      self.y += m.p.y;
      m.p.s--;

     self.draw();

      if (m.p.s == 0){
        clearInterval(anim);
      }
    }, 30);
  }

   this.create();
    this.draw();
    this.update();
}

function init(){
  var ship = new Ship(50, 50);
      }
```

Comment: You'll need 3 or more points to define a curve. Google "splines". If you have a velocity you could use that to define a third point by projecting forward from the start point in the initial velocity direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some useful information about this topic [here](http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/)

Basically, you need one or more control points to "bend" your vector into a curve.

[image] [image]

This can be achieved with the following formula for a single control point:
`[x,y]=(1–t)²P0+2(1–t)tP1+t2²P2`

When `t=0`, the right hand side equals the first control point – the start of the line segment. When `t=1`, we get the point P1, the second control point and the end of the line segment.